# Gridsome/Netlify CMS docs lead to broken Graphql

Tags: javascript, vue.js, netlify, netlify-cms, gridsome

I cannot setup Gridsome with NeflifyCMS by following Gridsome's [docs](https://gridsome.org/docs/guide-netlify-cms/)

Snippet for setting up Netlify config.yml

```
collections:
  - name: "posts"
    label: "Posts"
    folder: "posts"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Excerpt", name: "excerpt", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "date"}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
```

I go the Graphql Playground and open the Docs tab and see the "allPost" query but when I look inside of it "title" is not recognized as a field under post but for some reason "belongsTo" is. If you try to query for "title" you will get the error "Cannot query field 'title' on type 'Post'".

I have no idea where "belongsTo" came from or how to fix it. Is this a Netlify bug or a Gridsome issue?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short the docs are wrong, watch this videos instead https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryP1RMA7P9Y